# How to protect browser settings from changing by external programs

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I wonder if there's a way to protect webbrowser settings from changing by external programs. Few times I encountered a situation when after install a external program the  settings like 'start page' 'search engine' has changed. Is there any way to block it in Firefox or Chrom.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Windows. Most of the time there should be a `custom install` or `advanced install` option when you are clicking through the installation of the program where you can uncheck the changes that are going to be done to the browsers.

I don't think there's a way how to *block* the changes since you're explicitly allowing them through the installing program if you don't uncheck them.